# R Memory requirements

Tags: r, memory

I saved a fitted model to my local disc. The '.rda' file is 58 Mb in size. When I open a new instance of R (Mac OS X 10.6.8), and load the model as my first command, R requires 1.4 Gb of "Real Memory".

What's going on? I'm not loading any other libraries.
R version 3.0.2

Comment: File compression is what's going on, with a compression ratio of ~24.  This isn't unusual, depending on your data.  If you want more information, you'll have to say something about the shape and type of your data.

Comment: I honestly dont really know what it looks like. Its just a fitted randomForest model object that I'm saving to disc to avoid having recalculate the model when I restart R.

Comment: TMOTTM: Andrie's point is that if you check the size of the object you're saving to an `.rda` file in the first place, it's probably that big.